# VDI size increase not reflecting

Tags: filesystems, virtualbox, gparted

I have a dynamically allocated virtual disk, which was initially 40GB.

I increased the disk size from 40 GB to 100GB first and then also updated the partition using GParted as described here,
https://www.rootusers.com/use-gparted-to-increase-disk-size-of-a-linux-native-partition/

But still the disk size does not update,
df -h shows

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/I0--vg-root   35G   33G  1.3M 100% /
none                     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                     2.4G  4.0K  2.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs                    485M  564K  484M   1% /run
none                     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                     2.4G  4.0K  2.4G   1% /run/shm
none                     100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                236M   44M  180M  20% /boot
/home/iadm/.Private     35G   33G  1.3M 100% /home/iadm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root partition is on an LVM logical volume (LV) named `root` in a volume group (VG) named `I0-vg`, so you must first expand the underlying physical volume (PV), then expand the LV, then expand the filesystem:

```
pvresize /dev/<pv_dev>
lvresize --extents +100%FREE I0-vg/root
resize2fs /dev/mapper/I0--vg-root
```

where `<pv_dev>` is the block device of your LVM PV.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to resize the filesystem.

See

`man resize2fs` (for ext4)

or

`man btrfs-filesystem` (for btrfs).

Comment: iadm@lamp1:~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/I0--vg-root 75G
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The containing partition (or device) is only 9142272 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 19660800 blocks.

Comment: Just run `resize2fs /dev/mapper/I0--vg-root` without the new size.

Comment: Result is the same: The containing partition (or device) is only 9142272 (4k) blocks. I had tried that too. Its not increasing.